# Generated thrift file giving me compilation error - C#

Tags: c#, thrift

I have generated C# code using the thrift compiler command line, but when I included the .cs file in my Visual Studio 2010 project, it is not able to resolve thrift-related classes.

I know there is libthrift.jar for Java, but I could not find the dll or dependency for C# which needs to be added as reference to my project.

Can you please tell me where I can find the thrift related dlls for C#? I am using a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add reference to `Thrift.dll`

located under `thrift/lib/csharp/src/bin/Debug/Thrift.dll`

You better read the documentation http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageCSharp

OR you can download it as nuget package, check this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thrift/

To install Thrift, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

> PM> Install-Package Thrift

Comment: Thanks Damith but can you tell where I can find Thrift.dll